# ExtJS 4 how to add a static label field to a form that displays a data field from a store?

Tags: forms, extjs, label

I want to display some static (non-editable) fields on my form - for example record id.

I tried a [label](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Label) field, but it does not appear to have a way to wire it up to the data store/model like fields do.

I know I can add text fields and make them non-editable, but I prefer the look of having a text label.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [the display field](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Display) which is

> A display-only text field which is not validated and not submitted.